# Why can't I have async transformers in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a reason I can't use an asynchronous transformer when defining a Mongoose schema? Here's an example:

```js
const bookSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    transform: async function(v) {
      return Promise.resolve(v)
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is impossible because transformers are called in `toJSON` and `toObject` which are synchronous functions. Instead, make use of [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) (not as clean, but it gets the job done).